# Creating BizTalk 2006 adapters programmatically

Tags: scripting, powershell, biztalk

I'm writing a configuration script for a BizTalk server I need to create a few adapters.

In the "BizTalk Server Administration" application  this is done by going to Biztalk Server Group / Platform Settings / Adapters and choosing New / Adapter from the right-click menu.

I'd like to automate this process somehow, using a Powershell script or a SQL script. I tried to use the adm_Adapter_Create stored procedure in teh Biztalk DB but it doesn't work all the way as no send / recieve handlers get configured.

Is there any way to automate this adapter creation?

Comment: Don't know if this is a question for ServerFault.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use WMI for this with the [MSBTS_AdapterSetting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560016(BTS.20).aspx) class. There's some example code for this [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/cmcneill/archive/2005/04/05/28336.aspx).

Comment: Thank you!

Part of the script I wrote (if someone would need this in the future) is below

Answer (score 2):

Part of a Powershell script I wrote to solve this:

```
$adapterClass = [WMIClass] "root\MicrosoftBizTalkServer:MSBTS_AdapterSetting"

$adapter = $adapterclass.CreateInstance()
$adapter.Name = $adapterXml.name
$adapter.Comment = $adapterXml.comment
$adapter.Constraints = $adapterXml.constraints
$adapter.MgmtCLSID = $adapterXml.MgmtCLSID
$adapter.put() | Out-Null
```

Comment: I am getting an error for the put function called. It says put function requires an parameter to be passed. As I can see from the answer provided by tomasr above, PutOptions class object needs to be passed in put function. Can you help with it ?